# Quantlib: calling RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle() from another function

Tags: python-3.x, quantlib

I have one function that bootstraps a yield term structure (yts) using Quantlib.  I have attempted to make the resulting term structure re-usable by other functions, but I get error message:  "NameError:name'yts' is not defined  swap engine =ql.Discounting SwapEngine(yts)

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

```
def bootstrap():
    today = ql.Date.todaysDate()
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

    global yts
    yts = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
    estr = ql.Estr()

    ###  helper rates etc     

    estr_curve_c = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, ql.TARGET(),
                                            helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())
    estr_curve_c.enableExtrapolation()
    yts.linkTo(estr_curve_c)
 
    ### so far this works - the YieldTermStructureHandle works

def getrate(tenor, fwd):
    swapEngine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(yts)
    ir_swap = ql.MakeOIS(swapTenor=ql.Period(tenor, ql.Months), fwdStart=ql.Period(fwd, ql.Months),\
       overnightIndex = ql.Estr(yts), pricingEngine=swapEngine, fixedRate=2.0)
    return ir_swap.fairRate()     

####  this part does not work: NameError:name'yts' is not defined  swap engine =ql.Discounting     SwapEngine(yts)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way Python works:

```
>>> def init():
...     global x
...     x = 1
... 
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

The `init()` function needs to be executed, not just declared, for the global to be initialized.

However, if I can make a suggestion, I don't think that's a sound design.  Instead of making it a global, I would return `yts` from the `bootstrap` function.  You can either call `bootstrap` from `getrate`, or call it externally and pass `yts` to `getrate` as an additional argument.

Comment: I agree return yts is better.  But that still doesn't seem to solve my problem.  I am trying to use an xlwings UDF to apply the YieldTermStructureHandle to calculate a fwd rate in each excel cell the getrate function is used (ie create a matrix of fwds in excel).   It would also be useful to store yts objects to recreate past curves - is that possible?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with xlwings.  You can try the QuantLib mailing list; you might reach more people there with the expertise you need.